# E: Unable to locate package git

Tags: apt, git

I am trying to install git, I used `sudo apt-get install git` command and it results:

```
E: Unable to locate package git
```

This question have been asked by many people but not a single answer has fixed my problem, I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

P.s: I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: On what mirror are you doing this?

Comment: Local mirror, Pakistan, Is this what you asked? Or I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Which mirror should I use?

Comment: Pick any one you like. Maybe try one outside your country.

Comment: Yes, I suggest trying a different mirror.

Comment: Many thanks all of you, I changed my mirror to US and My problem is solved.

Comment: Your question was my answer, my solution was performing the update and upgrade commands. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 15):

You can add manually repository

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E1DD270288B4E6030699E45FA1715D88E1DF1F24
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git.list"

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: That won't work as `sudo echo ... >  /etc...` try it yourself first.

Comment: i did syntax mistake . now this working .

Answer (score 11):

I got this error after spinning up a Debian instance on DigitalOcean. The fix was to

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 1):

when you install Ubuntu package off-line usually in first of installation its cache doesn't get update so this error will occur and you have in your Ubuntu broken packages . for solution type in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

it will repair broken packages and after it you can continue.