# Error in getting source

Tags: 14.04, apt, git, source

I am new to the linux environment, I faced an issue while performing git clone, So I tried the solution mentioned in this link https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pycurl/+question/221185

But I am getting the following error while trying the 4th step mentioned in the link,

```
~/git-openssl$ apt-get source git    
Reading package lists... Done  
E: Unable to find a source package for git
```

How to resolve this issue and continue with my steps, Could somebody help me?

Comment: You miss the `sudo` in the command you use:

`sudo apt-get source git`  I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem, though.

Comment: No that is not the issue,  sudo apt-get source git
[sudo] password for test: 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for git

Comment: Check your apt sources in /etc/apt/sources.list. Do you have a line that looks like `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to locate package git](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557297/e-unable-to-locate-package-git)

Comment: @Novice: OP is looking to download the source package, not the binary package like in your linked question.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen: `apt-get source` doesn't require super-user privileges and if it did the error message would be different.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy git` as well as the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution walk through](https://techoverflow.net/2018/05/03/how-to-fix-apt-get-source-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list/)

**Solution:**
I had to edit the sourves.list and un-comment any lines that started with `deb-src`

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Change:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
```

To:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
```

Continue to un-comment any other lines that start with `deb-src`

Save the document and then do `sudo apt-get update`

now `apt-get source <package name>` should work

If above fails try `git clone https://repo.or.cz/r/git/debian.git/`